# Magento 2 : How to setup an option for customers to buy one year free shipping?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I`m a beginner in Magento 2. I did setup a shopping cart app with flat rate shipping. But now client wants to add a link in cart for buying premium membership, so that this particular users can shop without shipping charges for one year. Normal users will have to pay shipping charges as usual. Any idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a Customer Group. 
Stores > Other Setting and select Customer Group.
Add new customer group.

Go To Cart Rule please follow.
Marketing > Select Cart Price Rule > Add New Rule. now without using coupon and select free shipping in magento for that customer group .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing comes to my mind is Coupon code that he'll use everytime, with 1-year validity.